# How to maintain same layout style in all android device including tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-studio, native

I am developing a native Android application, how to maintain same design, font size, layout style in all android device including tablet also.

Comment: 1. Different dpi, 2. Mistake in layouts, 3. Mistake in graphics (drawables), 4. Wrong resource folders, and lot of another possibilities

Comment: This question is too broad and as @Miller has pointed out you need to add  more information to get any useful answers

Comment: @Miller can you can share me good resource or example of multiple screen layout.

Comment: @user3287910, you may start from discovering `https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html`. If you can share the essence of your resource files, the answer may be more substantive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both devices have different resolution, because of which the UI seemed different in two different devices. In Android Studio layout preview change the device size and resolution to see how your app looks on different screen sizes and resolutions.

Comment: i implemented different values/dimen.xml but seem it not affecting.